# GIven a numeric vector, x, how many elements determine y% of the sum

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector, `x`. I want to find the fewest number of elements that make up at least y% of `sum(x)`.  What's a good method for doing this?

For example, suppose

```
 x<-c(4,10,3,12,3,1,5,9,1,2,20,4)
```

`sum(x)` = 74.  So, the fewest number of elements that make up at least 30% of the sum is 2, because {20} makes up 27% of the sum and {20, 12} makes up 46%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
 min(which(cumsum(rev(sort(x))) > sum(x)*.3))
#[1] 2
```

`sort` returns in increasing order and you want in decreasing order, hence the need for `rev` or something equivalent. `which` would return all the positions after 2, hence the need for `min`.

Comment: That should do it.  Thanks